# Install Winsat on server 2012? Windows System Assesment Tool

Tags: performance, windows-server-2012, hard-drive

I use `winsat` to see my disk read/write speed on Windows 8 and it works great:

```
winsat disk -drive c
```

Can this be used on Windows Server 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[winSAT is a Windows module for client OSes, from Vista up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_System_Assessment_Tool).  It is not available for server OSes.

Comment: thanks. I now use atto dick benchmark. 0.23mb small and easy as i like it :)

Comment: Actually you can use it by copying it. Also there's such a thing as winserversat.exe from Microsoft that is similar. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200149.aspx

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use WinSAT in Windows Server 2012, you can copy `C:\Windows\System32\WinSAT.exe` from your Windows 8.x computer to the server.